# JTable cell validation via Regular expression

Tags: java, regex, swing, jtable, inputverifier

Is there a way to validate each cell of my JTable with Regular 
expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. get TreeModel from the table, get row and column count from the model, organize 2 loops and use getValueAt() method to get value for a particular cell.